# Watching when a file is created on network folder in linux

Tags: linux, nfs

I am trying to figure out a way to notice when a certain file is written to on the network folder mounted. I am aware that one can continuously probe the location to see if it has been created but that's very nice. I am also aware that one can use inotify, and derivatives of it like iwatch and inotify-tools, to look for kernel flags. However, it is a network folder the flags are not raised on the machine where the folder is mounted to.

So I was wondering if there are other ways to do this. I was thinking maybe use messaging queues like RabbutMQ. Check when the files are written and send message to a queue then read the message on mounted machine and do whatever?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't think the inotify suite of tools are appropriate here, and you're using Linux, try [Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) and an [existence or filesystem test](http://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#existence_testing) against the remote share.

```
 check file with path /nfs/appdata.txt
   if does exist then alert
```

Maybe a cleaner [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15962502/alarm-on-existence-of-file-in-monit). Is the filename known or not?

Comment: I just read the intro to Monit (http://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.pdf) and it wants a poll interval. So am I right in thinking it will just probe every X seconds?

Comment: Default is 60 seconds... but you can tune that appropriately.

Comment: Yeah that still does continuous probing I wanted something I little more clever and asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for a client to get notified when the mounted directory changed on the server (well, nfs v4.1 spec has a way to do it, but there are no implementations doing this). You have to poll.

If you can run a special applications on the server, then you can use something like lsync and have a custom handler to notify client with a mechanism of your choice.